# For loop that iterates through a nested dictionary and appends the results in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested, append

I would like to create a for loop that appends the license number of each vehicle into an empty list 'license_numbers = []'. However, it is only returning one item. Can someone help me?

```
cars = {'results':{'vehicle': {'specs': {'model': 'a', 'year': '2006'}},
                                'size': {'length': '4.5m', 'width': '1.7m'},
                   'colour': 'blue', 
                   'license': '1234'},
       
        'results':{'vehicle': {'specs': {'model': 'b', 'year': '2008'}},
                                'size': {'length': '3.5m', 'width': '1.2m'},
                   'colour': 'red', 
                   'license': '5678'}}
```

I have tried something along the lines of the below but I am only returned with ['1234'] when I would like (['1234'], ['5678']) to be returned :

```
license_numbers=[]

for x in cars:
    license_numbers.append(cars['results']['license'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have duplicate key `results` in your dictionary - which isn't possible in Python.

Comment: "However, it is only returning one item" Yes, because `cars` only *contains* one item. Try printing it out to see. If you don't understand why, please review a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary in python cannot have multiple similar keys. I think a workaround to this is to have one key holding a list of dictionaries like so.

```
cars = {'results1':[{'vehicle': {'specs': {'model': 'a', 'year': '2006'}},
                                'size': {'length': '4.5m', 'width': '1.7m'},
                   'colour': 'blue', 
                   'license': '1234'},
       {'vehicle': {'specs': {'model': 'b', 'year': '2008'}},
                                'size': {'length': '3.5m', 'width': '1.2m'},
                   'colour': 'red', 
                   'license': '5678'}]}
```

With this we can easily use list comprehension to gather every license.

```
license = [car.get('license') for car in cars['results1']]
```

output

```
['1234', '5678']
```